# Admin panel is down due to compilation issues. Admin panel is down with 500 error

Tags: magento-1.9, compilation

One of my website admin panel is down usually.

Once i disable the compilation it works normally but after few hours site goes down and in mentioned file first line changed by its own.

`/var/www/html/includes/config.php`

```
Warning: include(/var/www/html/includes/src/Magpleasure_Filesystem_Helper_Data.php): File not found  in /var/www/html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94

    #0 /var/www/html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php(94): mageCoreErrorHandler()
    #1 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(546): Varien_Autoload->autoload()
    #2 /var/www/html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu.php(325): Mage::helper()
    #3 /var/www/html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu->_isEnabledModuleOutput()
    #4 /var/www/html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu.php(171): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu->_buildMenuArray()
    #5 /var/www/html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu.php(98): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu->_buildMenuArray()
    #6 /var/www/html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/menu.phtml(30): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu->getMenuArray()
    #7 /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php(3428): include()
    #8 /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php(3459): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView()
    #9 /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php(3473): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
    #10 /var/www/html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #11 /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php(2617): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #12 /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php(2335): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #13 /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php(2279): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml()
    #14 /var/www/html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(53): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml()
    #15 /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php(3428): include()
    #16 /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php(3459): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView()
    #17 /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php(3473): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
    #18 /var/www/html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #19 /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php(2617): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #20 /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php(28881): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #21 /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php(14360): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
    #22 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(43): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
    #23 /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php(14388): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
    #24 /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php(18880): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch()
    #25 /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php(18410): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match()
    #26 /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php(21346): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #27 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run()
    #28 /var/www/html/index.php(102): Mage::run()
    #29 {main}`
```

Is any third party is the culprit for this?

Comment: Have you r-compiled after third party module installed?

Comment: @Abdul I toggle the line manually in the above file not from backend and currently i dont installed any new extension

Comment: @Abdul is changing from file and compiling from backend is same in terms of their effect.

Comment: have you disabled compilation in admin?

Comment: @Abdul not yet sir

Comment: Pls disable compilation & check

Comment: @Abdul sure will inform here soon. Thank You

Comment: @Abdul i compiled it and then disabled it from backend while doing this HHVM is crashed but now its working. I hope it wont go down due to this issues again .Thank You